# How to pass option into HTML select

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I want different behaviors depending on which `<option>` element is selected:

```
<select name="colorSelector" onchange="handleColorChange();">
    <option value="">- select -</option>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
</select>

function handleColorChange() {
    // Behave different depending on which <option> was just selected
}
```

What do I need to pass into the `handleColorChange()` method from inside the `onchange` listener in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like noone has mentioned `switch` yet. Also, don't put the function in the HTML, that's just bad. Here is the right way:

```
document.getElementsByName( 'colorSelector' )[ 0 ].onchange = function ( ) {
    switch ( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value ) {
        case '1':
            // Do something when "Red" is selected
            break
        case '2':
            // Do something when "Blue" is selected
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: if it's in a form he can also use `document.forms[0].elements['colorSelect'].onchange` (assuming it's the first form on the page... or if you would prefer you can give your form a `name` and call it using that.

Comment: I know. I was just adding that info ***in case*** the OP *does have it available* :P cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function handleColorChange(self)
{
   console.log(self.selectedIndex);
   console.log(self.options[self.selectedIndex].text);
   console.log(self.options[self.selectedIndex].value)
};
```

And in HTML code

```
<select id="mySelect" name="colorSelector" onchange="handleColorChange(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to pass anything to function, just assign an id to select:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="colorSelector" onchange="handleColorChange();">
    <option value="">- select -</option>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
</select>

function handleColorChange() {
var x=document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
var y=document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
}
```

Or If you want to get by name then do this in your function:

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("colorSelector")[0].selectedIndex;
var y=document.getElementsByName("colorSelector")[0].options;
alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this`

```
<select name="colorSelector" onchange="handleColorChange(this);">
    <option value="">- select -</option>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
</select>

function handleColorChange(element) {
    // Behave different depending on which <option> was just selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="colorSelector" onchange="handleColorChange(this);">
    <option value="">- select -</option>
    <option value="1">Red</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
</select>​


function handleColorChange(obj) {
    alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
}​
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TkkuJ/)